# Unterminated entity reference in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, php-7

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// 27/01/2016 Edit:
$result = mysql_query("A Long mysql query");
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement('<rss version="2.0" />');
$products = $rss->addChild('products');
///
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$product = $products->addChild('category');
$product->addChild('product_id',"$row[product_id]");
$product->addChild('cat_id',"$row[cat_id]");
$product->addChild('cat_name',"$row[cat_name]");
$product->addchild('product_code',"$row[product_code]");
$product->addchild('product_name',"$row[product_name]");
$product->addChild('description','$row[description]');
$product->addchild('rating',"$row[rating]");
$product->addchild('image_url','$row[imag_url]');
$product->addchild('price',"$row[price]");
$product->addchild('discount',"$row[discount]");
$product->addchild('stock_status',"$row[stock_status]");
$product->addchild('stock_quantity',"$row[stock_quantity]");
$product->addchild('weight',"$row[weight]");
$product->addchild('length',"$row[length]");
$product->addchild('width',"$row[width]");
$product->addchild('height',"$row[height]");
$product->addchild('colour',"$row[colour]");
$product->addchild('size',"$row[size]");
$product->addchild('material',"$row[material]");
$product->addchild('pattern',"$row[pattern]");
};

Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($rss->asXML());
?>
```

and here is the error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]: unterminated entity reference _Coke.jpg in C:\wamp\www\rabwah\core.php on line 40

The error is in the line with `'$row[imag_url]'`.

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: `'$row[imag_url]'` should be `"$row[imag_url]"`.  Change single quotes to double quotes.  Also you forgot the `/>` in `$rss->addChild('<products');`.

Comment: Don't know if its relevant here or not but `addChild` is the method not `addchild` also this line `$products = $rss->addChild('<products');` appears to be in error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat and @jason McCreary and @Orangepill the problem with ` $rss->addChild('<products');` has been fixed it is now  $rss->addChild('products'); but the issue is still there

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This correctly encodes the `& < >` and `"" ''`

```
$parent->addChild($name, htmlspecialchars($value));
```

Answer (score 47):

`SimpleXMLElement` is actually a system resource which behaves like an object. Which makes working with loops tricky. So when trying to add new child elements
instead of this:

```
$product->addchild('element', $value);
```

do this:

```
$product->element = $value;
```

or you can use `htmlspecialchars()`, to escape html characters.

**Note:**

`mysql_*` is deprecated as of [php-5.5](/questions/tagged/php-5.5) and removed as of [php-7](/questions/tagged/php-7). So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 9):

My solution to this is specifically creating a text node, which makes sure absolutely everything is escaped properly:

```
$cell = $dom->createElement('td');
$cell->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value));
```

Comment: This is not SimpleXMLElement, this is DOMDocument.

Comment: @ermannob DOMDocument does indeed have the `createTextNode` method: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php

Answer (score 3):

If you use the new created node you can set the value by accessing {0} property. This should escape any special characters.

```
$childNode = $parent->addChild($name);
$childNode{0} = $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving an old question, but there is another solution to this..
Assuming the following code causes the "unterminated entity reference" error:

```
$xml->addChild($key,$value);
```

@Joel-Davey's solution works very well:

```
$xml->addChild($key,htmlspecialchars($value));
```

But you can also do the following if, for some reason, you don't want to use the above htmlspecialchars function (basically, you split the one step into two steps):

```
$xml->addChild($key); 
$xml->$key=$value;
```

i have no idea which one will execute faster; i doubt it'd make much of a difference, but, this works, and i thought it should be mentioned

PS: i know it works because i'm using it on a [personal project](https://github.com/petersphilo/MissingNPRPodcasts-phpPort)

Comment: Absolutely! in my (very basic) tests the second uses a **super-tiny** bit more memory than the first, but seems to execute a **super-tiny** bit faster

Comment: @mega6382: i added a link to a personal project, you can see it in action 'in the wild'

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing -

```
$product->addchild('image_url','$row[imag_url]');
```

To

```
$product->addchild('image_url',"$row[\"imag_url\"]");
```

OR

```
$product->addchild('image_url',$row['imag_url']);
```

**EDIT**
wrap quotes too round image_url, courtesy  [Barrmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is:

```
$product->addchild('image_url',htmlspecialchars($row['imag_url']));
```